# Resizing standalone table for image inclusion into PowerPoint

Tags: standalone, png, export, powerpoint

I'm attempting to use the standalone package to create large tables to import to Microsoft PowerPoint. When I have attempted to use the 'size' and 'density' commands, the image looks very blurry after importing to PowerPoint. I have only been able to increase the table size by increasing the font size, which changes the dimensions and reduces the weight of `\midrule` etc. I apologize for any faux pas, this is my first post.

```
\documentclass[convert={size=1080,outext=.png},border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone,tikz,booktabs,mathtools,threeparttable,dcolumn,bold-extra,caption,siunitx,multirow,upgreek,fixltx2e,float,xfrac,graphicx,anyfontsize}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{42}{50}\selectfont

\minipage{2.5\linewidth}

\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{B}[3]{>{\boldmath\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
\makeatother

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ l  .  .  .  .  . }
\toprule
Source & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DOF} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%SS} \\ 
\toprule
A & 15.84           & 1 & 15.84 & \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}    {17.89}\tnote{*}  &  \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{10.29}\tnote{\textdagger}   \\ 
B & 64.33           & 1 & 64.33 & \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{72.69}           &  \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{41.82}  \\ 
C & 22.43           & 1 & 22.43  & \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{25.34}          &   \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{14.58}\\ 
D & 1.50            & 1 & 1.50  & 1.70                                          & 0.98 \\ 
\addlinespace
A$\times$B & 22.49  & 1 &  22.49 &\multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{25.41}           &  \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{14.62}\\ 
A$\times$C & 3.29   & 1 & 3.29  & 3.72                                          &2.14 \\ 
A$\times$D & 3.44   & 1 & 3.44  & 3.88                                          & 2.23\\ 
B$\times$C & 7.02   & 1& 7.02   & \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{7.93}                & 4.56\\ 
B$\times$D & 6.94   & 1 &  6.94  & \multicolumn{1}{B{.}{.}{-1}}{7.84}               & 4.51\\ 
C$\times$D & 2.13   & 1 & 2.13  & 2.41                                          & 1.38\\ 
\addlinespace
Error & 4.43            & 5     & 0.89  &                                               & \\ 
\addlinespace
Total & 153.82      & 15 &      &                                               & \\    
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
\item [*] Bold entries in the F ratio column designate values greater than an F\textsubscript{cr} of 6.61 at a  confidence limit of P = 95.
\item [\textdagger] Bold entries denote \%SS values greater than 10\% of the total SS.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\endminipage
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: powerpoint won't take `png` as such. It will try to convert it first to some other acceptible format like `jpg`. In this process your resolution may be lost. So, convert directly to `.jp` using `size=1080,outext=.jpg` and try to insert. Don't scale fonts, but scale the image in powerpoint. Best way is to use `beamer`, say bye bye to power point.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. To be more explicit, I'm just dragging the LaTeX output .pdf into the PowerPoint, don't know if that was incorrect. I'll look into beamer, but this presentation is due in two days and I don't want to mess around with it with such little time.

Comment: Dragging should *not* be done. You should use `insert` function of power point. Use a jpg image directly. Don't allow power point to convert.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong then, because no .jpg file is created, only the standard .pdf. Is standalone supposed to create a second .jpg file?

Comment: You will need `imagemagick` installed for that. I converted your table in to jpg and inserted in to power point and it looks alright. I didn't use large fonts.

Comment: I installed Imagemagick and GhostScript to open the .pdf files. Did you change anything in my code? When I try to save the file as a .jpg it is lower resolution than I saw previously.

Comment: I removed the fontsize command (`\fontsize{42}{50}\selectfont`). Then ran `pdfcrop` on that pdf file (`pdfcrop myfile.pdf myfilecropped.pdf`). and the converted to jpg (`convert -density 900 myfilecropped.pdf myfilecropped.jpg`). Then in power point go to menu `Insert` and `picture` choose this jpg file. Thats all. [If you want the tex file click this](http://pastebin.com/yHyQ77MT)

Comment: [Image link if you want](http://i.imgur.com/O1AXdxA.jpg)

Comment: PowerPoint actually supports the inclusion of PNG images (at least in version 2010) and this format should be used for screenshots and similar, not JPG which decoder is designed for photos and will cause ugly artifacts with screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for bold faced numbers aligning. It is described in [Josip W. article](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) on page 73. I adopt it to @Mico solution as:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,caption,siunitx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new

\newcommand{\ubold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font

\robustify\ubold% <-- new
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.2]
                       S[table-format=2.1] % <-- corrected
                  *{3}{S[detect-weight,table-format=2.2]} }% <-- new
\toprule
Source & {SS} & {DOF} & {MS} & {F\tnote{*}} & {\%SS\tnote{\textdagger}} \\
\midrule
A & 15.84 & 1 & 15.84 & \ubold 17.89 & \ubold 10.29\\% <-- see new way of use of \ubold
B & 64.33 & 1 & 64.33 & \ubold 72.69 & \ubold 41.82\\
C & 22.43 & 1 & 22.43 & \ubold 25.34 & \ubold 14.58\\
D &  1.50 & 1 &  1.50 & 1.70          & 0.98 \\
\addlinespace
A$\times$B & 22.49  & 1 &22.49 & \ubold 25.41 & \ubold 14.62\\
A$\times$C & 3.29   & 1 & 3.29 & 3.72 & 2.14 \\
A$\times$D & 3.44   & 1 & 3.44 & 3.88 & 2.23 \\
B$\times$C & 7.02   & 1 & 7.02 & \ubold 7.93 & 4.56 \\
B$\times$D & 6.94   & 1 & 6.94 & \ubold 7.84 & 4.51 \\
C$\times$D & 2.13   & 1 & 2.13 & 2.41 & 1.38 \\
\addlinespace
Error & 4.43        & 5 & 0.89 \\
\addlinespace
Total & 153.82      & 15 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[*] Bold entries in the F column denote values greater than an F\textsubscript{cr} of 6.61 at a  confidence level of $P = \SI{95}{\%}$.
\item[\textdagger] Bold entries in the \%SS column denote values greater than \SI{10}{\%} of the total SS.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, I add package `etoolbox` for macro `\rustify`, change nice definition for boldface font and adequately change its use in selected cells. Now the table is:

[image]

**Edit:** Since I do not use PowerPoint, I don't know for all possibilities how to import LaTeX generated table into it.  I test to include table as `jpg`  picture, obtained by pdf to jpg conversion with services of  web page pdf2jpg.net with selected pixel resolution 300 dpi. I'm satisfied with its results:

[image]

For above picture i change preamble of file and table as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,
               12pt,% <-- bigger base fonts
               prewiev]{standalone}
    \usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,caption,siunitx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \newcommand{\ubold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
    \robustify\ubold

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\Large % or \Large or \huge, select on trial basis
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}% for bigger distance between column
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.2]
                       S[table-format=2.1] 
                  *{3}{S[detect-weight,table-format=2.2]} }%
\toprule
 ...
```

Original table width was 12.01 cm. I manually enlarge this to 16 cm. Result you can see on above snippet of PowerPoint editor. Hope this gives some ideas, what you can do.

Anyway, in the first place I gives more attention how to generate nice looking table in LaTeX. By the way, if you include LaTeX table in PowerPoint, is not very sensible make table title in LaTeX, better is to do this in PowerPoint.

Comment: Ingenious use of `\robustify`. Oddly, though, the bold font that ends up being used is the "standard", i.e., "bold extended" CM font rather than the "un-extended" version. This behavior also occurs under MacTeX2015.

Comment: i dont know if it happened only for me, but compilation failed and got the error `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (-): c used.`, in fact several other errors too.

Comment: @SAM, indeed ... now I see, that I forgot to add `%` before `<-- corrected` . Now the code is corrected and works (tested).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `size` AND `density` options of `convert` then the PDF is rastered to a PNG with the given density and afterwards resized to the requested size, which makes larger density setting ineffective again. I would simply recommend to drop the `size` setting and only use a suitable density. I would start with 600 (dpi) and go from there up or down as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the resizing is about. I would use a "normal" `standalone` document class and resize the table inside powerpoint. I would recommend, though, that you use a non-extended bold font for the numbers in the table; doing so will make it much easier to "line" up the numbers, visually speaking.

In the code below, I use the facilities of the `siunitx` package to achieve alignment of the numbers on the decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,caption,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\newcommand{\ubold}[1]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont#1} % non-extended bold font
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table Caption}
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.2] 
                   S[table-format=2.0] 
              *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\toprule
Source & {SS} & {DOF} & {MS} & {F\tnote{*}} & {\%SS\tnote{\textdagger}} \\ 
\midrule
A & 15.84 & 1 & 15.84 & \ubold{17.89} & \ubold{10.29}\\ 
B & 64.33 & 1 & 64.33 & \ubold{72.69} & \ubold{41.82}\\ 
C & 22.43 & 1 & 22.43 & \ubold{25.34} & \ubold{14.58}\\ 
D &  1.50 & 1 &  1.50 & 1.70          & 0.98 \\ 
\addlinespace
A$\times$B & 22.49  & 1 &22.49 & \ubold{25.41} & \ubold{14.62}\\ 
A$\times$C & 3.29   & 1 & 3.29 & 3.72 & 2.14 \\ 
A$\times$D & 3.44   & 1 & 3.44 & 3.88 & 2.23 \\ 
B$\times$C & 7.02   & 1 & 7.02 & \ubold{7.93} & 4.56 \\ 
B$\times$D & 6.94   & 1 & 6.94 & \ubold{7.84} & 4.51 \\ 
C$\times$D & 2.13   & 1 & 2.13 & 2.41 & 1.38 \\ 
\addlinespace
Error & 4.43        & 5 & 0.89 \\ 
\addlinespace
Total & 153.82      & 15 \\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[*] Bold entries in the F column denote values greater than an F\textsubscript{cr} of 6.61 at a  confidence level of $P = 95\%$.
\item[\textdagger] Bold entries in the \%SS column denote values greater than 10\% of the total SS.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice solution, however the `ubold` numbers are not aligned at decimal point: see column before last one (numbers `7.93` and `7.84`).

Comment: @Zarko - Yeah, I noticed that too. Not sure what's going on; it may be a bug in the `siunitx` package. For sure, the problem isn't caused by `\ubold`-- it arises with `\textbf{...}` and `\bfseries` as well. I'll need to write to Joseph W. to ask if this is a bug.

Comment: @Zarko - I can get that size to print, but what I'm concerned about is the projection getting blurry. Is it possible to make the image larger, it appears that any changes I make to the size or density have no effect on the final image. Also, I'm attempting to do this with about 5 tables, so I'm trying to keep the formatting generalizable.

Comment: @Mico, I foggy remember, that this  was issues ones on SE, and solution was use option, how to parse a number (I'm not sure).  Anyway, it will be nice, if such issues will be emphasized in siunitx manual. Please ask Joseph W. for this too.

Comment: @LuccaGiannechini, my test show clear and crisp normal and bold faced numbers. As I mentioned, only aligning of bold numbers doesn't obey decimal point but are aligned to the left of declared integer part of number.

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks for looking into this issue and for suggesting a work-around. Unfortunately, the workaround doesn't deliver for me, either on a Mac running MacTeX2015 or a Wiindows 7 machine running MikTeX2015. What's so weird about this issue is that `\ubold` -- both my original version and your modified version -- works correctly on the first five rows of the table but not later on.

Comment: @Mico, I resolve the problem of aligning bold numbers. It works anywhere in table (in cells with numbers) .  I use 64-bit MikTeX  on W10 OS, if this matter. See my answer below.

Comment: @Zarko - the topic of the OP was the difficulty in increasing the size and resolution of the printed table using the standalone package. The issue did not derive from the alignment or misalignment of the bold cells.

Comment: @LuccaGiannechini, in my answer I give information, what can be done regarding this. My test show, that quality of imported jpg file with table picture with 300dpi gives satisfactory result. I will emphasize this in my answer again.  Anyway, to me is important that in the first place we solve the table generation, dealing with PowerPoint is not topic of this list, I think so.