# Align numbers by decimal point using siunitx and bfseries

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am looking for help regarding number alignment along the decimal point.

Here is the code that I use so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox, siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
 group-digits  = false,
 table-sign-mantissa,
 table-space-text-post = *,
 parse-numbers=false,
 detect-weight=true,
 detect-shape=true,
 detect-mode=true
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\robustify\bfseries
\caption{My-caption}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=4.4, detect-all] lS[table-format=4.4,           
 detect-all]>{\bfseries} S[table-format=4.4, detect-weight] S[table-     
 format=4.4, detect-weight] @{}} 
\toprule
   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Low}}  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Med} \\ \midrule                           

  MV    & 1.64    & 1.14    &  1.58   \\                                                                        
        & (1.17)  & (0.97)  &  (0.87) \\                                           
  AG    & 2.61    & 1.36    &  1.07   \\                                 
        & (1.17)  & (0.88)  &  (0.64)  \\   
  BM    & 2.08    & 1.14    &  0.44    \\                                               
        & (0.98)  & (0.86)  &  (0.29)  \\   
  MOM   & 0.74    & 0.28    &  -0.34   \\                                         
        & (0.31)  & (0.12)  &  (-0.17)   \\                                            
  TA    & \bfseries 1.90 & 1.03  &  0.88 \\                                                         
        & (1.63)   & (1.75)  &  (1.06)    \\                                                  
\Xhline{3\arrayrulewidth}
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I want the numbers to be aligned by decimal point, but want to highlight some of them in bold without having the alignment crashed like this.

Comment: Add the \documentclass and \begin{document} /\end{document} so that we can compile the example without have first to edit it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! adding to what Ulrike Fischer said add `\usepackage{makecell}` oterwise `\Xhline` is not reconized.

Comment: See if my answer on question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275324/resizing-tables-using-the-standalone-package can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Zarko for your comment! I includes \usepackage{threeparttable} and \roubstify\ubold - my numbers are aligned but the respective number is not bold...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that your answer is actually continuation of your question (I suggest to edit your question and move it there).

Problem in aligning of cells content and boldface fonts for some of them is in option `parse-numbers=false`. Without it all with exception of cells of form `(-0.01)` works as expected, those cells generate errors. This can be prevented by putting them into curly braces: `{(-0.03)}`, however it is not aligned as desired anymore.

For the particular case of table in question, can be used dirty trick shown in the code below, which mitigate this problem.  See, if result is satisfactory.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new
\newcommand{\ubold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\robustify\ubold

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{My Caption}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l *{6}{S[input-symbols = {()},
                              table-space-text-post=\ ,% <-- for spacing of )
                              detect-weight,
                              table-format=-1.2]}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Panel A: Univariate Sorts Based on $\beta_{\sigma,t}$}                   \\ \midrule
       & \mc{Low}       &           & \mc{Med}  &           & \mc{High} &  \mc{High-Low}    \\ \midrule
   MV  & 1.64           & 1.14      &  1.58     & 1.08      & 1.45      &                   \\
       & (1.17)         & (0.97)    &  (0.87)   & (0.64)    & (1.03)    &                   \\
  TA   & \ubold 1.90    & 1.03      &  0.88     & 0.87      & 1.35      &                   \\
       & (1.63)         & (1.75)    &  (1.06)   & (0.43)    & {(-0.03)} % <--- here is problem
                                                                        &     {~~~}         \\
   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Trick is in added space for right parenthesize in column formatting.

**Addendum**
After three years I would write this table as follows:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <-- new
\usepackage{xparse}     % <-- new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{1}m} % <--
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty= ,  % <-- new
         input-close-uncertainty= , % <-- new
         table-space-text-pre=(,    % <-- new
         table-space-text-post=),   % <-- new
         table-align-text-pre=false,% <-- new
         detect-weight,
         mode=text,                 % <-- new
         table-format=-1.2}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <-- new
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}                        % <-- changed
    \caption{My Caption}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ l *{6}{S} }        % <--- changed
    \toprule
\mc[7]{Panel A: Univariate Sorts Based on $\beta_{\sigma,t}$}       \\
    \midrule
    &\mc{Low}&        &\mc{Med}&        &\mc{High}& \mc{High-Low}   \\
    \midrule
MV  & 1.64   & 1.14   &  1.58  &  1.08  &   1.45  &   \\
    & (1.17) & (0.97) & (0.87) & (0.64) & ( 1.03) &   \\
\addlinespace
TA  &\B 1.90 & 1.03   &  0.88  &  0.87  &   1.35  &   \\
    & (1.63) & (1.75) & (1.06) & (0.43) & (-0.03) &   \\    % <--- changed
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

All changes in comparison to original code are marked by `% <---`. Result now has more consistent appearance (correct align at decimal points, correct minus sign, width of boldface digits ares equal to normal ones):

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you very, very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the suggestion by Zarko:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,caption,siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
group-digits  = false,
table-space-text-post = *,
parse-numbers=false,
}

\newcommand{\ubold}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My Caption}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{7}{S[detect-weight,table-format=4.4]}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Panel A: Univariate Sorts Based on $\beta_{\sigma,t}$}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \midrule
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{Low}}  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Med}   &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{High}    &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{High-Low}         \\ \midrule
   MV  & 1.64   & 1.14  &  1.58  & 1.08  & 1.45 &   \\                
       & (1.17) & (0.97)  &  (0.87) & (0.64) & (1.03) &  \\            
  TA   & \ubold 1.90   & 1.03 &  0.88 & 0.87  & 1.35  & \\                
       & (1.63) & (1.75)  &  (1.06)  & (0.43) & (-0.03)&  \\           
   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

But I get the following output:[image]

Does anybody see my mistake?

Comment: you miss/forgot on  main command in preamble of my answer: `\robustify\ubold` which had to follows `\newcommand{\ubold}{...}`

Comment: @Zarko as i tested previously it doesn't work in this case, because there isn't just numbers

Comment: I added \robustify\ubold after the command \newcommand{\ubold}{...} - but unfortunately, this does not do the trick :-(

Comment: There is conflict between options in `\sisetup`, temporary I haven't time to look closely, what can be done. Maybe latter evening ...

Comment: Your help would be very much appreciated, Zarko!

Comment: @Funnybunny, ups, I forgot to respond on your comments and answer :-(. After four year ... : culprits are: `parse-numbers=false` and way of writing negative numbers in parenthesis. Cure: replace your `sisetup` with mine from the second example and use for table specification `\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S}}`. Nicer result (where `mode=text` will take an effect) you will obtain if for definition of `\ubold` you will use: `\newrobustcmd\ubold{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}`.