# Emphasize numbers in tables

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

I want to have some numbers in my table bold. But get some troubles with the decimal points of the numbers. Here is my code for it:

```latex
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{r|SSS|SSS|S}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$r$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{1}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{2}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{3}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{1}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{2}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$IC_{3}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{$\mu_{i}$}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    \midrule
    1     & 0.60  & 0.65  & 0.65  & 0.61  & 0.66  & $\mathbf{0.79}$  & 0.40 \\
    2     & 0.45  & 0.55  & 0.55  & 0.46  & 0.56  & 0.84  & 0.15 \\
    3     & 0.35  & 0.49  & 0.50  & 0.37  & 0.52  & 0.93  & 0.10 \\
    4     & 0.26  & 0.45  & 0.45  & 0.28  & 0.48  & 1.02  & 0.10 \\
    \toprule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}% 
end{document}
```

Is there some general solutions, which can be used for other tables as well? Thank you!

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Align numbers by decimal point using siunitx and bfseries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318372)

Comment: Although you can align correctly the decimals as showed the egreg's answer, the bold font is bigger, so warping the left-right limits of the columns is unavoidable, and is not very nice. My suggestion is highlight using a dark red font  or discrete cell background, some mark or better, do not highlight anything and explain clearly  in the caption or the main text  what is important in the table and why.

Answer (score 13):

Use the proper `siunitx` feature:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{}\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabular}{
 r
 *{7}{S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
\addlinespace[6pt]
$r$ & {$IC_{1}$} & {$IC_{2}$} & {$IC_{3}$} & {$IC_{1}$} & {$IC_{2}$} & {$IC_{3}$} & {$\mu_{i}$} \\
\addlinespace[3pt]
\midrule
1 & 0.60  & 0.65  & 0.65  & 0.61  & 0.66  & \bfseries 0.79  & 0.40 \\
2 & 0.45  & 0.55  & 0.55  & 0.46  & 0.56  &           0.84  & 0.15 \\
3 & 0.35  & 0.49  & 0.50  & 0.37  & 0.52  &           0.93  & 0.10 \\
4 & 0.26  & 0.45  & 0.45  & 0.28  & 0.48  &           1.02  & 0.10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I removed the `\multirow` tricks; if you really want more vertical space before and after the column headers, use `\addlinespace` as shown; but it's not required and I wouldn't do it.

[image]

Comment: thank u for your reply. just for understanding: u defined 7 columns with the S command from package siunitx and u defined manually the table-format with 1.2, which should indicate one number infront of the decimal point and 2 numbers after the decimal point? thank you

Comment: @alix correctly deduced.

Comment: @alix Yes; only specifying `S` gives a default, which might not be good for the specific table.