# Problem with a table with special header: bolded numbers are badly aligned with the rest of the numbers

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I am trying to make a LaTeX table that includes special headers. My code for the table is shown below:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{0.70}{
\begin{tabular}{lddcdd}
\toprule
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{M1} & 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M2} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{5-6}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1-2} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7-8} & 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1-2} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7-8} \\ 
\midrule
A &   \textbf{0.0021} & \textbf{0.0033} & & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
B & \textbf{0.0052} & \textbf{0.0042} & & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
C & \textbf{0.0082} & \textbf{0.0057} & & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
D & 0.0107 & 0.0097 & &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
E & \textbf{0.0080} & 0.0088 & &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
F & 0.0140 & 0.0148 & & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
G & 0.0128 & 0.0176 & & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
H & 0.0157 & 0.0164 & & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
I & 0.0145 & 0.0155 & & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
K & 0.0236 & 0.0225 & &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\smallskip
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
```

it creates a table like this:

[image]

but I want the bolded numbers to align nicely with un-bolded numbers...How can I make the bolded numbers to align the other numbers in the right way? Thank you,

Comment: please add complete compilable code as a MWE  -- the d type of column in the table is not described

Comment: you could try this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318372/align-numbers-by-decimal-point-using-siunitx-and-bfseries/318388#318388

Answer (score 3):

With use of `S` columns (defined in `siunitx` package) and robust command for marking cells with number in boldface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}  % <---
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}  % <---
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <--- 
\newrobustcmd\B{%
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries} % <===
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{detect-weight, 
         mode=text, % <===
         table-format=1.4}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l SS S[table-format=-1.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{M1}  &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{M2}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   {1-2}   &   {7-8}       &   {1-2}   &   {7-8}       \\
    \midrule
A   &\B 0.0021  &\B 0.0033      & -2.37     &  0.00         \\
B   &\B 0.0052  &\B 0.0042      & -1.23     &  0.67         \\
C   &\B 0.0082  &\B 0.0057      & -0.21     &  1.08         \\
D   &   0.0107  &   0.0097      &  0.74     &  1.41         \\
E   &\B 0.0080  &   0.0088      &  5.05     &  5.05         \\
F   &   0.0140  &   0.0148      & -2.37     &  0.00         \\
G   &   0.0128  &   0.0176      & -1.23     &  0.67         \\
H   &   0.0157  &   0.0164      & -0.62     &  1.10         \\
I   &   0.0145  &   0.0155      & -0.21     &  1.08         \\
K   &   0.0236  &   0.0225      &  5.05     &  5.05         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*

- don't use `\scalebox`, it scale also fonts in table (you lost control over their size)
- it is sufficient is determine 5 columns and mark group with `\cmidrule(r){2-3}` and `\cmidrule(l){4-5}`

**Edit:**

In the definition

```
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
```

the `{b}` denotes "non-extended bold". That is reason why text marked by `\B` occupies the same width as regular-weight text. This property -- as is pointed out in @Mico comment -- is exactly what's needed for display numerals in a tabular settings. That it can be exploited by `siunitx`, it must be in the `text-mode`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. After editing my code according to your recommendation, I get the string `[rm]bfb` right before all of my bolded numbers. I am not sure why this is occuring. Could you please tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: @chico0913, this is not possible. I also test your following up question, and it works. So, you check out, what you really have in the your real document. Provided MWE works! Showed result for sure is not produced by showed MWE. See my comment below your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568146/

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318416/197451

I have not used the `d` column instead used `S` column to specify numbers in the second column

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <-- new
\usepackage{xparse}     % <-- new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{1}m} % <--
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \sisetup{ input-open-uncertainty= ,  % <-- new
            input-close-uncertainty= , % <-- new
            table-space-text-pre=(,    % <-- new
            table-space-text-post=),   % <-- new
            table-align-text-pre=false,% <-- new
            detect-weight,
            mode=text,                 % <-- new
            table-format=1.4}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <-- new
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}                        % <-- changed
    \caption{My Caption}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S}        % <--- changed
    \toprule[2pt]
\mc[2]{Panel A}       \\
    \midrule
 &\mc{M1}\\
\midrule
B  & 0.0140\\
\addlinespace
C  &\B 0.0140 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The decimal markers aren't aligned in the table, and the bold-extended font weight is in use. Please replace `\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}` with `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b} \let\B\bfseries` to get a better (typographic) outcome.

Comment: output is further skewed

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention `\robustify\B` after `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b} \let\B\bfseries`