# Problem with making table with special header that includes bolded numbers

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

I am the author of the question:
[Problem with a table with special header: bolded numbers are badly aligned with the rest of the numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568080/problem-with-a-table-with-special-header-bolded-numbers-are-badly-aligned-with)

Following Zarko's advise, I have revised my code according to his suggestion to get my bolded number aligned in the right way.
However, a new problem is popping up. I am making another post because I can't share the updated version of my code in my previous post.

I am trying to make a table with special header.

I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{NAACL2019}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,times}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % <---
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <--- 
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries} % <===

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _last_

\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text, table-format=1.4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l SS 
            S[table-format=-1.2]
            S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M1}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M2} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {1-2} & {7-8} & {1-2} & {7-8} \\ 
\midrule
A & \B{0.0021} & \B{0.0033} & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
B & \B{0.0052} & \B{0.0042} & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
C & 0.0960     & \B{0.0054} & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
D & \B{0.0082} & \B{0.0057} & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
E & 0.0107     & 0.0097     &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
F & \B{0.0080} & 0.0088     &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
G & 0.0140 & 0.0148 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
H & 0.0128 & 0.0176 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
I & 0.0157 & 0.0164 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
J & 0.0145 & 0.0155 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
K & 0.0205 & 0.0209 &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
L & 0.0236 & 0.0225 &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%}
\smallskip
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
```

But it gives the following result:

[image]

The problem here is that there is `[rm]bfb` right before each bolded number, which I want to remove.

How can I resolve this issue?

PS: For my LaTeX document, I am using this specific template for a particular academic conference: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/instructions-for-naacl-hlt-2019-proceedings/xyyfwfkswhth

This conference template is 2-columned, that is, the texts are displayed on each page in 2 columns.

Thank you,

Comment: Before you even take a look at the pdf, fix all the error messages you get. Also, clean up your preamble to make youre you don't load packaes multiple times. Lastly, make sure, `hyperref`is the last package in your preamble (There are only a few exceptions, that should be loaded after it.)

Comment: Having fixed the errors related to the preamble/packages, we still end up with an error message such as "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.". This is caused by an extra `&` throughout the whole table. To fix this, replace all occurences of two subsequent `&` by a single`&`.

Comment: Ok, I will fix them right now

Comment: @leandriss there is not extra `&` in the table, because I am using `\multicolumn`. The extra `&` are meant to be there.

Comment: The error message is caused because you use more columns than you declared. With `\begin{tabular}{l SS S[table-format=-1.2]S[table-format=1.2]}` you declare a total of 5 columns, while a line such as `G & 0.0140 & 0.0148 & & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ ` uses a total of 6 column. Thus replace `& &` with a single `&`.

Comment: BTW, table produced  provided MWE, is narrow enough that it can be placed in the single column.

Comment: After clean up your document preamble (remove twice loaded package, push `hyperref` on the end of preamble) and remove curly braces around numeral marked by `\B` (this was not done in my answer  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568080/problem-with-a-table-with-special-header-bolded-numbers-are-badly-aligned-with/568085#568085 !) I'm not able to reproduce your problem. You should be careful using my solution/suggestion ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote,

> a table with special header that includes bolded number

I can see no bolded numbers in the "special header". What I do see is a number of specious and unnecessary `&` symbols that are causing various issues. Remove them, and the code compiles fine.

I can also see no reason for employing the `\scalebox` directive -- unless, that is, you want to deliberately sabotage the look of the table. Oh, please don't load `latexsym` if you also load `amssymb`, and please don't load packages more than once.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xurl} % 'xurl' is more capable than 'url'
%%%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,%%%epsfig,times
  }
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % <---
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <--- 
\newrobustcmd\B{%
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries} % <===

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _last_
 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text, table-format=1.4}
\centering
%\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{tabular}{l SS 
            S[table-format=-1.2]
            S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M1}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M2} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {1-2} & {7-8} & {1-2} & {7-8} \\ 
\midrule
A & \B{0.0021} & \B{0.0033} & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
B & \B{0.0052} & \B{0.0042} & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
C & 0.0960     & \B{0.0054} & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
D & \B{0.0082} & \B{0.0057} & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
E & 0.0107     & 0.0097     &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
F & \B{0.0080} & 0.0088     &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
G & 0.0140 & 0.0148 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
H & 0.0128 & 0.0176 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
I & 0.0157 & 0.0164 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
J & 0.0145 & 0.0155 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
K & 0.0205 & 0.0209 &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
L & 0.0236 & 0.0225 &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%}
%%\smallskip
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply. after done all the changes that you recommend, I still get the `[rm]bfb` right before each bolded number in the table, which I want to remove; I don't know why this is happening...could you help me with that?

Comment: Also, I need to use the scalebox since my LaTeX template is two-columned. If I use it without scalebox, then the table goes outside of the border for a single column

Comment: Also, after your recommended changes, I get the `undefined sequence` error on my table.

Comment: @chico0913: Which control sequence is undefined specifically? Regarding the use of `\scalebox`: There are better ways to make sure your table fits into the available space. `\scalebox` just results in inconsistent font sizes. Alternatively, you could use something like `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} \small \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l SS 
S[table-format=-1.2] S[table-format=1.2] }` For more techniques, see also: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: Hello, I am getting undefined sequence error for the rows A,B,C, and D.

Comment: @chico0913 - The code I posted does *not* generate errors. If you are getting errors in *your* document, it *must* be the case that your code differs materially, in some ways, from mine; unfortunately, my psychic divination skills are worthless, and hence I'm in no position to tell what these material differences might be. If you're using a two-column format, that's something which is (a) quite important and (b) worthy of mentioning up front in your query. Finally, I've never before heard of an "undefined sequence" error message. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mico as David has pointed out 
(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568151/removing-rmbfb-that-appears-before-each-bolded-number-in-the-table?noredirect=1#comment1432331_568151), this was due to the version of my texlive was 2019. After switching to texlive 2020, I was able to resove the issue.

Comment: Is the `NAACL2019.sty` LaTeX style file available online? It doesn't appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Incidentally, why do you keep loading `latexsym` and `epsfig`, and what's the purpose of loading `times` twice?

Comment: yes. I included the link for the overleaf NAACL template in my question here. Also, note that the table itself is not my entire LaTeX document. My entire document is 8 pages long, which I need to use the packages `latexsym` and `epsfig` for certain parts. Anyway, the issue is resolved now after switching to texlive 2020, thanks to David.

Comment: @chico0913 - The `latexsym` package was superseded by the `amssymb` package in 1994; the `epsfig` package's functionality is subsumed by that of the `graphicx` package.