# Removing `[rm]bfb` that appears before each bolded number in the table

Tags: tables, fonts

I am the author of the question:
[Problem with a table with special header: bolded numbers are badly aligned with the rest of the numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568080/problem-with-a-table-with-special-header-bolded-numbers-are-badly-aligned-with)

Following Zarko's advice, I have revised my code according to his suggestion to get my bolded number aligned in the right way.
However, a new problem is popping up. I am making another post because I can't share the updated version of my code in my previous post. The previous post does not address the new problem I am facing.

I am trying to make a table with special header.

I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{NAACL2019}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,epsfig,times}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % <---
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <--- 
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries} % <===

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _last_

\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text, table-format=1.4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l SS 
            S[table-format=-1.2]
            S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M1}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{M2} \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {1-2} & {7-8} & {1-2} & {7-8} \\ 
\midrule
A & \B{0.0021} & \B{0.0033} & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
B & \B{0.0052} & \B{0.0042} & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
C & 0.0960     & \B{0.0054} & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
D & \B{0.0082} & \B{0.0057} & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
E & 0.0107     & 0.0097     &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
F & \B{0.0080} & 0.0088     &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
G & 0.0140 & 0.0148 & -2.37 & 0.00 \\ 
H & 0.0128 & 0.0176 & -1.23 & 0.67 \\ 
I & 0.0157 & 0.0164 & -0.62 & 1.10 \\ 
J & 0.0145 & 0.0155 & -0.21 & 1.08 \\ 
K & 0.0205 & 0.0209 &  0.74 & 1.41 \\ 
L & 0.0236 & 0.0225 &  5.05 & 5.05 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%}
\smallskip
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
```

But it gives the following results:

[image]

More specifically, I am getting the following errors:

1. `undefined control sequence` for the rows A, B, C, and D
2. and `overfull warning` for the entire table.

Also, the NAACL template that I am using can be found at:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/instructions-for-naacl-hlt-2019-proceedings/xyyfwfkswhth

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: without an example code it is hard to comment, but do you not get an error message? If you want help with an error always better to show the error message than the pdf output (which is not intended to be usable after an error) also what release of latex are you using (the commands used assume a fairly new release)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have included the details of the error message in my post here...thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: The posted code works in texlive 2019 and 2020, in texlive 2018 or older you get `! Undefined control sequence.
\B ->\DeclareFontSeriesDefault 
                               [rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries `

Comment: I am using overleaf to be more specific......does the `\DeclarFontSeriesDefault` only applicable to LuaLaTeX and such? I am using overleaf `PDFLaTeX`

Comment: You should show the whole error message or preferable the whole log from a small test document then we would know which release you have. The code assumes a newish latex, although a version could be made for old latex too if updating latex is not an option. But in general for _any_ error don't even look at the pdf, tex's error recovery does not try to make sensible pdf output.  Unrelated but don't use epsfig for any documents written this century.

Comment: you can use texlive 2020 on overleaf check the sidebar menu which texlive you are using (they have 2017,2018,2019,2020 available if I recall correctly) [it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc7Z9.png)

Comment: Hello thank you so so so much for your help. After switching to texlive 2020, I am able to see the correct result. Thank you again! :) You could make your comment as the answer so that I can give you an upvote and choose your comment as the answer.

Comment: Why you not follows showed suggestion in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568080/problem-with-a-table-with-special-header-bolded-numbers-are-badly-aligned-with/568085#568085. There is nowhere used `&\B{<some number>} & ...` but only `&\B <number> & ...`. Test of your MWE with repairing this errors and add missed \begin{document} and end{document} works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never ignore error messages (it is unfortunate that on overleaf they show the pdf even in case of error, look out for the red circle!)

The commands used in the example require a reasonably new latex (texlive 2020 or an updated 2019) fortunately overleaf has texlive 2020 available, you can check in the sidebar which texlive you are using:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again David for your earlier comments and this answer! your insight solved my problem